# run function in separate thread in winapi c++ application

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, edsdk

I need to run this fuction in separate thread:

```
EdsError downloadEvfData(EdsCameraRef camera)
{
    EdsError err = EDS_ERR_OK;
    // some code skipped
}
```

I call this function like this:

```
HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL,0,downloadEvfData,camera,0,NULL);
```

But get this error:

```
invalid conversion from 'void (*)(EdsCameraRef)' {aka 'void (*)(__EdsObject*)'} to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE' {aka 'long unsigned int (__attribute__((stdcall)) *)(void*)'}
```

How can I fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you allowed to use C++11 [thread library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread), i.e. `std::thread`s? If not, why? See also [Qt](http://qt.io/) and [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) libraries

Comment: Yes, I can use C++11 thread library

Answer (score 0):

Your `downloadEvfData` function doesn't have the expected `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` signature, you can do something like this instead (if `EdsCameraRef` is a pointer) :

```
EdsError downloadEvfData(EdsCameraRef camera)
{
    EdsError err = EDS_ERR_OK;
    // some code skipped
}

DWORD ThreadProc(PVOID camera)
{
    downloadEvfData((EdsCameraRef)camera);
    return 0; // thread exit return
}


HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, camera, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks! But ```downloadEvfData((IUnknown*)camera);``` gets this error: ```cannot convert 'IUnknown*' to 'EdsCameraRef' {aka '__EdsObject*'}```

Comment: refresh the page. I was using some test code :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this line ```HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, camera, 0, NULL);``` gets this error now: ```invalid conversion from 'DWORD (*)(PVOID)' {aka 'long unsigned int (*)(void*)'} to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE' {aka 'long unsigned int (__attribute__((stdcall)) *)(void*)'} [-fpermissive]|```

Comment: Not sur what your EdsCameraRef  is but you must pass a pointer to ThreadProc.

Comment: Problem fixed by using: ```DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID camera)```. Unfortunately, the whole application hangs now ((

Comment: This won't work because thread entry point must use `stdcall` calling convention. Which is typically declared using `WINAPI` macro.

Comment: @AntonVakulenko I guess `camera` is not a pointer, maybe you need to try `downloadEvfData(*((EdsCameraRef*)camera));`. If the program hangs, maybe you need to show [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without private information?

Answer (score 0):

EDSDK's example do as this to create a thread

```c
static EdsError downloadEvfData(void* param)
{
    EdsError err = EDS_ERR_OK;
    EdsCameraRef camera = (EdsCameraRef)param;
    // some code skipped
}

HANDLE _hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthread(dowloadEvfData, 0, camera);
```

you can use c++11 to create a thread as this

```c
std::unique_ptr<std::thread> pthd(nullptr);
pthd.reset(new std::thread([&]){
   downloadEvfData(camera);
})
pthd->join();
```

One important note

```c
//When using the SDK from another thread in Windows, 
// you must initialize the COM library by calling CoInitialize 
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
//....
CoUninitialize();
```